# D flip-flop BCD upcounter

Tags: digital-logic, pspice

I am trying to design BCD upcounter (0~9) using Dff in Pspice.

From the state table below, my optimized boolean expression is like this:

input D8 = Q4Q2Q1 + Q8Q1’
input D4 = Q4’Q2Q1 + Q4Q2’ + Q4Q1’
input D2 = Q8’Q2’Q1 + Q2Q1’
input D1 = Q1’
output Y = Q1Q8 (for 9 to 0 reset)

[image]
​

with that expression i made it like this

[image]

[image]

But, the result was not what i think... from 8 D8 FF is not working. At first, I thought the delay was the problem, so I changed DIGMNTYMX setting to minimum, but still no change.  What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

U2B:Q (Q8) is activating whilst U1A:Q (Q1) is still high (following the end of state 7). That's the first problem; you get a full reset of all the flip-flops: -

[image]

The second problem (and this is one of design) is that if you want the digit 9 to be counted to then, you should reset on the first occurrence of digit 10.

---

**23 hours later**

You changed the design but you didn't fix the overlap problem: -

[image]

Try adding two inverters in series with the Q8 output that feeds the resetting AND gate and, you might get lucky and create just enough delay to avoid the overlap that creates the false reset. Please do try and read all my answer and implement fixes for both issues. In other words if I tell you there are two problems then two problems need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! From your advice i changed "output Y = Q1Q8" to "output Y = Q2Q8" to prevent full reset and design problem but i still got q8 not working...

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your clear function. Tie all CLR lines high, just as you did with PRE.
Take your bottom NAND gate and call this output Z. Z is high except on a count of 9. Replace the both NAND gates feeding Q2 with NAND gates one input larger, and drive both new inputs with Z.

If you extend your truth table to a count of 10, you will see that it is identical to a count of 0 for Q1 and Q4, so you need only need an additional term on Q2 to force it to 0 on count 9. Q8, of course, only responds to counts 7 and 8, so that will handle the 9-0 transition naturally.

Your problems are a classic example of why combining synchronous (D inputs) and asynchronous (PRE and CLR) inputs is a perilous task. Once you have started using synchronous logic, DO NOT try to add asynchronous feedback. It often ends in heartbreak, and for more reasons than you have encountered here. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Changed Y =Q1Q8 to Y = Q2Q8 and result

[image]

Comment: For a short time the counter shows a wrong output as ripple counters do. This may or may not meeting the demands